# Execute a java program from nifi with parameters

Tags: minify, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi, hortonworks-sandbox

i want to take some terms from a cassandra database, and then send them as a parameter to java program which will output some data that i will need to save in a cassandra database.

Is this possible with nifi, if yes, which processors to use? specially for the execution of the java program, since i've seen that processors for cassandra already exists.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache NiFi provides a number of options for running custom Java code:

- **External Process** - Apache NiFi's 
  [ExecuteProcess](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.2.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteProcess/index.html) and [ExecuteStreamCommand](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.2.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand/index.html) processors can be used to run any external process and return the output as flowfile content.  ExecuteProcess does not pass an input stream, where ExecuteStreamCommand streams the input flowfile content via stdin.  Both processors accept arguments formatted with NiFi Expression Language.  These processors do not care if your process is Java, it just runs as an external process.  This is probably the fastest, easiest way to run your code.
- **Custom Processor** - You can also create a custom processor to run your Java code in a more NiFi-native way.  This requires some extra work, but would provide the best performance for high volumes, if that is a concern.  The [NiFi Developer Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html#processor_api) can help.
- **Scripting** - A third approach would be to use the [ExecuteScript](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.2.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/index.html) or [InvokeScriptedProcessor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.2.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.InvokeScriptedProcessor/index.html) processors to run a Groovy script that uses your custom Java code.  This is a good way to experiment with running your code as a custom NiFi processor without all of the overhead of coding a full Processor implementation.